# Bar chart with two series of different date/values ranges

Tags: primefaces, charts, jqplot

I am using **jqplot** through **Primefaces** and Have input to Bar Chart like this:

```
Series 1:
 label: "Company 1"
 data: {"01-05-2015": 10, "06-05-2015": 3}
Series 2:
 label: "Company 2"
 data: {"03-05-2015": 10, "06-05-2015": 3}
```

When I pass this data as `BarChartModel`, I got data wrongly drawn on the chart.

The data follows the first series, as the `Series 2` is drawn after the `Series 1` dates. I've to  convert the data to be as follows in order to get the chart drawn fine:

```
Series 1:
 label: "Company 1"
 data: {"01-05-2015": 10, *"03-05-2015": 0*, "06-05-2015": 3}
Series 2:
 label: "Company 2"
 data: { *"01-05-2015": 0* ,  "03-05-2015": 10, "06-05-2015": 3}
```

Notice the data items between * and *.

Any advice here? (if using `DateAxis` helps?)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with LinearChartModel when I has not using DateAxis.
As a workaround, I filled my series with all possible data and then reordered the list. Urg!

Should work with BarChartModel too.

Using DateAxis you just need to add your date axis with the timestamp, like this:

```
serie.set(new Date().getTime(), new Double(123));
```

or this

```
serie.set("2015-09-08", new Double(123));
```

Put the DateAxis in your LineChartModel like this:

```
DateAxis axis = new DateAxis("Data da inspeção");
linearModel.setZoom(true);
linearModel.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, axis);
linearModel.setExtender("linhaSetor");
```

And format your date in the extender.js:

```
function linhaSetor() {
    this.cfg.axes.xaxis.tickOptions = {
        show : true,
        angle : 45,
        formatString : '%d/%m/%y %Hh'
    };
}
```

You don't even need to put the data in order.